# NestJS cannot resolve dependencies

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to add a servicerequestservice into ordersservice

and I keep getting this error. est can't resolve dependencies of the ServiceRequestsService (ServiceRequestRepository, [object Object], CounterService, ?, +). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [3] is available in the ServiceRequestsModule context.

I tried forward reffing the dependancies to eachother like the documentation but this also does not seem to help.

service-requests.module.ts

```
import { ServiceRequestsService } from './service-requests.service';
import { ServiceRequestsController } from './service-requests.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ServiceRequest } from './entities/service-request.entity';
import { OrdersModule } from 'src/orders/orders.module';
import { ProductsModule } from 'src/products/products.module';
import { OrderItemsModule } from 'src/order-items/order-items.module';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ServiceRequest]), forwardRef(() => OrdersModule), ProductsModule, OrderItemsModule,],
  controllers: [ServiceRequestsController],
  providers: [ServiceRequestsService]
})
export class ServiceRequestsModule {}
```

orders.module.ts

```
import { forwardRef, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { OrdersService } from './orders.service';
import { OrdersController } from './orders.controller';
import { Order } from './order.entity';
import { OrderItemsModule } from 'src/order-items/order-items.module';
import { ProductsModule } from 'src/products/products.module';
import { CommentsModule } from 'src/comments/comment.module';
import { RetailersModule } from 'src/retailers/retailers.module';
import { PurchasesModule } from 'src/purchases/purchases.module';
import { DeliveriesModule } from 'src/deliveries/deliveries.module';
import { ServiceRequestsModule } from 'src/service-requests/service-requests.module';


@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Order]), forwardRef(() => OrderItemsModule), forwardRef(() => ServiceRequestsModule), ProductsModule, CommentsModule, RetailersModule, PurchasesModule, DeliveriesModule],
  providers: [OrdersService],
  controllers: [OrdersController],
  exports: [OrdersService]
})
export class OrdersModule {}
```

service-requests.service.ts

```
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { CounterService } from 'src/counter/counter.service';
import { OrderItemsService } from 'src/order-items/order-items.service';
import { Order } from 'src/orders/order.entity';
import { OrdersService } from 'src/orders/orders.service';
import { Product } from 'src/products/product.entity';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/products/products.service';
import { PurchasesService } from 'src/purchases/purchases.service';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { CreateServiceRequestDto } from './dto/create-service-request.dto';
import { UpdateServiceRequestDto } from './dto/update-service-request.dto';
import { ServiceRequest } from './entities/service-request.entity';
import {format} from "date-fns";

@Injectable()
export class ServiceRequestsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(ServiceRequest)
    private repo: Repository<ServiceRequest>,
    
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => OrdersService))
    private readonly orders: OrdersService,
    private readonly counter: CounterService,
    private readonly purchases: PurchasesService,
    private readonly orderItems: OrderItemsService,

  ) {}
```

order.service.ts

```
import { forwardRef, Inject, Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { FindConditions, getMongoRepository, MongoRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Order } from './order.entity';
import { isValidObjectId } from 'mongoose';
import { OrderItemsService } from 'src/order-items/order-items.service';
import { DeliveriesService } from 'src/deliveries/deliveries.service';
import { CounterService } from 'src/counter/counter.service';
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import {format, parseISO, toDate} from 'date-fns';
import { formatAddress } from 'src/addresses/address.entity';
import { PurchasesService } from 'src/purchases/purchases.service';
import { ActivitiesService } from 'src/activities/activities.service';
import { CommentsService } from 'src/comments/comment.service';
import { ServiceRequestsService } from 'src/service-requests/service-requests.service';


// let lastSku = 0;

@Injectable()
export class OrdersService {
  constructor(
    
    @InjectRepository(Order)
    private repository: Repository<Order>,

    @InjectRepository(Order)
    private mongoRepository: MongoRepository<Order>,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => OrderItemsService))
    private readonly orderItems: OrderItemsService,

    @Inject(forwardRef(() => PurchasesService))
    private readonly purchases: PurchasesService,
    private readonly deliveries: DeliveriesService,
    private readonly counter: CounterService,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => ServiceRequestsService))
    private readonly service_request: ServiceRequestsService,
    private readonly comments: CommentsService,
    private readonly activities: ActivitiesService,
  ) {
  }
```

purchases.module.ts

```
import { forwardRef, Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { PurchasesService } from './purchases.service';
import { PurchasesController } from './purchases.controller';
import { Purchase } from './purchase.entity';
import { OrderItemsModule } from 'src/order-items/order-items.module';
import { ForecastModule } from 'src/forecast/forecast.module';
import { ProductsModule } from '../products/products.module';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Purchase]), forwardRef(() => OrderItemsModule), ForecastModule, ProductsModule],
  providers: [PurchasesService],
  controllers: [PurchasesController],
  exports: [PurchasesService]
})
export class PurchasesModule {}
```

Purchases.service.ts

````
import { BadRequestException, forwardRef, Inject, Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { getMongoRepository, IsNull, MongoRepository, Not, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Purchase, PurchaseItem } from './purchase.entity';
import { isValidObjectId } from 'mongoose';
import { OrderItem } from 'src/order-items/order-item.entity';

import { OrderItemsService } from 'src/order-items/order-items.service';
import { ForecastService } from 'src/forecast/forecast.service';
import { getDate, getWeek, toDate , format} from 'date-fns';
import {CounterService} from "../counter/counter.service";
import { ProductsService } from 'src/products/products.service';
//import { ProductsService } from '../products/products.service';

@Injectable()
export class PurchasesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Purchase)
    private repository: Repository<Purchase>,
    private orderItems: OrderItemsService,
    //private productsService: ProductsService,
    private forecast: ForecastService,
    private readonly counter: CounterService,
    private readonly products: ProductsService,
  ) {}```
````

Comment: Does `ProductsModule` exports `PurchasesService`?

Comment: im adding it to the file

Comment: how would I import that like this?


@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Product]), RetailersModule],
  providers: [ProductsService],
  controllers: [ProductsController],
  exports: [ProductsService, PurchasesService]
})
export class ProductsModule {}

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like you have a circular dependency (or at least a circular file reference) between the `ServiceRequestService` and the `PurchasesService`. Nest can't resolve the name of the `PurchasesService`, so you may need to `forwardRef` it, like you've done for the `OrderService` already

---

Edit:

After seeing the structure of the `PurchasesService` it would appear that this is happening because there is indeed a circular reference, but not like one you'd usually see. So `ServiceRequestService` imports `OrdersService` and `OrdersService` imports `ServiceRequestService`. This circular dependency is already taken care of. Now, `ServiceRequestService` (SRS) also imports `PurchasesService`, but `PurchasesService` imports `OrdersService` which imports `SRS`, making another cyclic dependency. To resolve this, the `PurchasesService` should `forwardRef` the `OrdersService` and the `OrdersService` should `forwardRef` the `PurchasesService` and the `SRS` should `forwardRef` both the `OrdersService` and the `PurchasesService`. This *should* take care or the `cannot resolve dependency` error.

Side note: you may have more circular dependencies to deal with. Make sure you are watching your imports and that they resolve in a way that does not make a cyclic dependency.

Comment: this didn't change the error for me.

Comment: For any more details, you'd need to add the `PurchasesSerivce` to the question, because that's what Nest is having a hard time resolving here

Comment: I have added the file to the post. thanks.

Comment: Where's the `PurchasesService` file?

Comment: My bad i've added it now.

Comment: im still getting errors but I don't know which dependency to resolve now. It says theres still a issue with importing servicerequests into ordersmodule : Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the OrdersService (OrderRepository, OrderRepository, [object Object], [object Object], DeliveriesService, CounterService, ?, CommentsService, ActivitiesService). Please make sure that the argument ServiceRequestsService at index [6] is available in the OrdersModule context.

Comment: Your `OrdersService` injects `ServiceRequestService` so your `OrdersModule` should have `ServiceRequestModule` in the `imports` and `ServiceRequestModule` should have `ServiceRequestService` in both the `providers` and `exports`. From there, resolve circular dependencies as required